# how to create a custom mvc structure in virtuemart

Tags: virtuemart

I want to add one more category(import products data ,under orders listing) to the order so that can have its own mvc pattern

any help!

[image]

Comment: sorry under products listing

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For adding new menu on the VM Left menu,

you have to create an entry on `#__virtuemart_adminmenuentries`

for adding uder products `Module Id - 1 and parent Id - 0`

Also you have option for adding your view name, and task according to new MVC section.

You can simply create a custom MVC (layouts ) by copying any `view + controller+ model` if its have tables check the `tables` folder too and rename it to your view name Then add it on the VM Left Menu.

Hope its helps..